# using a interface to type a anonymous object in typescript

Tags: typescript, strong-typing

I have a Interface IBase and a variable that contains a few other objects (in the sample i just added base for a better demonstration)

```
interface IBase {
    height?:number;
    width?:number;
}

var element = {
    base: {

    }
}
```

How can I say that the object that the varable element.base has is from the type IBase? I know that I could create a type for the element variable that contains the types of base etc, but is that also a possibility to type that scenario without doing so.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Van den Brink's answer is good. Just as a demo another option :

```
var element = {
    base: <IBase> {

    }
}
```

This will give the desired intellisense as well :

[image]

Comment: Using a type assertion here only gets you partial benefits because it will allow you to coerce to a type that your object literal doesn't actually meet the spec for. That is, it gets you intellisense but doesn't get you a good static type check. AFAICT the only way to get a static type check is to assign the literal to a variable of the correct type without a type assertion. Dick van den Brink has the better answer IMO.

Answer (score 12):

If you change the declaration of var element to the following it knows what base is:

```
var element: { base: IBase; } = {
    base: {
    }
}
```

Note: you can also create a new interface for it like this which makes it a bit more reusable:
    interface IElement {
        base: IBase;
    }
and then use it like here:
var element: IElement = { base: {} }

Answer (score 9):

The excellent answer from @basarat now needs a little updating; using the angle brackets now produces a `tslint` error:

> [tslint] Type assertion using the '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead. (no-angle-bracket-type-assertion)

The solution is a simple one:

```
const element = {
    base: {} as IBase
}
```

This also provides the intellisense (auto-complete) that you'd want as well.

Comment: This helped me greatly, as I was looking for an answer when applying a default fallback object when null-coalescing (??) through potential object sources.

E.g.:


    const someData : SomeDataInterface = source1 ?? source2 ?? { /* Defaults */ } : SomeDataInterface

Comment: Tslint is the one saying the syntax is forbidden. Angle brackets is still very much a valid way of casting

Answer (score 7):

You have accidentally caused yourself a problem with your interface declaration. It is a subtle one that you will come across with structurally typed languages.

```
interface IBase {
    height?:number;
    width?:number;
}
```

Because all of the properties are optional, the interface is essentially `{}`. i.e. any object satisfies this interface. That's too general to be useful in most cases.

For example, it is perfectly acceptable to do this:

```
var x: IBase = {
    a: 'efsdsdf',
    v: 'sdfdsf' 
};
```

I think you'll agree that *really* this object is not useful anywhere I wanted to use an `IBase` object.

With this out of the way, you may find the most graceful solution is to create an interface that matches your `element` definition.

```
interface IElement {
    base: {
        height?:number;
        width?:number;
    }
}

var element: IElement = {
    base: {
        height: 4
    }
}
```

Comment: Typescript may have improved this sine this post.  Your example does give me an error:

Type '{ a: string; v: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IBase'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'a' does not exist in type 'IBase'.(2322)