# Nonspecific properties and typed this in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

#### Input

```
const obj = {
    foo: function() {
        this.car = 4;
        this.can("far");
    },
    bar: function() {
        this.caz = ["fa", "ba"];
        this.car = 7;
    }
}
```

#### Attempt

```
interface IObj {
    [index: string]: IObjVar;
}

interface IObjVar {
    car?: number;
    can(arg: string)?: void;
    caz?: string[];
}
```

However this fails to bring code-completion. I want to type `this.` and `car`/`can`/`caz` to show up.

Comment: I know little about TypeScript, but shouldn't you [let your anonymous object implement that interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264681/using-a-interface-to-type-a-anonymous-object-in-typescript)?

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right, it's something like that. Anyway, will keep experimenting with the syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking for is not possible until at least [issue #3694](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3694) is fixed. The type of `this` inside a function that is not part of a class declaration is always `any`. The best you could do is to alias `this` to some other variable with the correct type:

```
const obj = {
    foo: function() {
        const self: IObjVar = this;
        self.car = 4;
        self.can("far");
    },
    bar: function() {
        const self: IObjVar = this;
        self.caz = ["fa", "ba"];
        self.car = 7;
    }
};
```

or you could always explicitly cast `this`:

```
const obj = {
    foo: function() {
        (<IObjVar> this).car = 4;
        (<IObjVar> this).can("far");
    },
    bar: function() {
        (<IObjVar> this).caz = ["fa", "ba"];
        (<IObjVar> this).car = 7;
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks, not a perfect solution, but good to know it's an actual issue rather than my misunderstandings of the docs :). [+1 & accepted]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be a bit DRY (don't repeat yourself) you can capture the type of the variable using a `type` declaration. Sample :

```
const obj = {
    foo: function() {
        let self: ObjType = this;
        self.car = 4;
        self.can("far");
    },
    bar: function() {
        let self: ObjType = this;
        self.caz = ["fa", "ba"];
        self.car = 7;
    },

    car: 123,
    caz: [],
    can: function(x:string){}
}

type ObjType = typeof obj;
```

Comment: What's the `let` syntax, how does it differ from other bindings?

Comment: I just use `let` instead of `var` whenever possible. Simplified : `let` creates a new scoped variable in blocks (`{}`) e.g. `if`/`while` etc. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/let.html